# Add buttons to svg-object with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm building a graph in javascript using nvd3 and need to add a couple of custom buttons.

using d3 I only seem to have an append-object. In my current setup, self.selector is a svg-element.

```
d3.select(self.selector).insert("button")
```

I consider a few options:

- Target self.selectors parent and insert html-elements for toggling that way.
- Target the svg and insert some kind of svg-buttons that I could access using javascript.
- Use some other native js method to insert the hmtl-elements I want before the svg.

Are there any pro:s or cons with any of theese methods? I don't use jQuery in this project.

Comment: I just went through this on a project.  My initial approach was to use html inputs, `d3.select('body').append` and then absolutely position them on the svg.  I found the differences, though, in how you position an HTML element vs an SVG element to be a pain.  So, I ended up using the approach @Marcel recommends.  `d3` created SVG elements that are style to look like fancy inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding SVG shapes, style them with CSS to look like the buttons you want and register and event listener.
That works fine and is the cleanest approach.

Comment: Can I add a event-listener to svg in the same way as any "regular" element?

Comment: If you are using `d3`, why not just use [.on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on) for events?

Comment: Yes, works the same way. Or as Mark pointed out there is a framework specific short-cut.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add HTML button elements to SVG, the SVG containers (svg and g) cannot hold buttons. You can add foreignObject to an SVG canvas (or g element) which can hold buttons but svg:foreignObject is not supported in IE.